# Sending an mail to my own webmail service without showing mail composer view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webmail

I would like to do a feedback in my IOS application .Hence, When the User typed in their feedback ,the mail will be send to my webmail without showing user the iPhone mail composer view.I am using roundcube for my webmail.

I really have no idea where have to start . Any kind soul that can help me with this.

Those answer did not really answer my question . Like API eBay, after a payment transaction is complete . A message will send to the sever to tell the seller that the use is buying this and had pay for it. I wan to know how the message is being sent.Thank you

Comment: Have you not even done a search of this site?

Comment: Yes I did research on those.. But I did not know how to push to my webmail ... I don't quite understand ... Sorry.. I just started learning Xcode programing this month...

Comment: It's generally never a good idea to do something as major and privacy-invasion-y as turning a user's phone into a spam-bot.  You can send an email through mail frameworks like MailCore and LibEtPan, but getting the credentials of the user that owns said device is entirely up to you.

Comment: The MailCore and LibEtPan are good frameworks. But It Is too complex for me...I keep getting libetpan.framework file not found.